# Gstreamer plugins not found by gst-inspect-1.0

Tags: gstreamer, pkg-config

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with Anaconda Python distribution. I installed gstreamer-1.0 libraries using Synaptic. I wanted to test my installation with: `gst-inspect-1.0 fakesrc` (as suggested in the [docs](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/frequently-asked-questions/using.html)) but I get the following error:

`No such element or plugin 'fakesrc'`

So, I tried just typing `gst-inspect-1.0`. This told me that it looks like none of the plugins were successfully installed:

```
staticelements:  bin: Generic bin
staticelements:  pipeline: Pipeline object
Total count: 1 plugin, 2 features
```

I don't understand why no plugins are found because I had already installed through Synaptic the libraries: `libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0`,`libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0`,`libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0`, `libgstreamer-1.0-0` as well as all the `-dev` versions. I also made sure that I removed the old `gstreamer0.10*` plugins so that they wouldn't interfere.

Finally, I checked the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0` and noticed something that might be causing the problem:

```
-pthread -I/home/guel/anaconda2/include/gstreamer-1.0 
-I/home/guel/anaconda2/lib/gstreamer-1.0/include 
-I/home/guel/anaconda2/include/glib-2.0 
-I/home/guel/anaconda2/lib/glib-2.0/include 
-I/home/guel/anaconda2/include 
-L/home/guel/anaconda2/lib -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

It looks like the required libraries are inside the Anaconda directories. Could that somehow prevent the `gst-inspect-1.0` binary (which is in `/usr/bin`) to link to those libraries? My `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` contains the directory `/home/guel/anaconda2/lib/pkgconfig`.

Sorry if the question is too naive; I'm a beginner with `pkg-config` and linking libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by first realizing that I had modified my `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` in my `.bashrc` file in order to add some custom `pkgconfig` paths for libraries like ffmpeg and anaconda (I had added e.g. `/opt/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig`). However, I forgot to keep the default paths in `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and simply overwritten the variable with the new ones with `export` command.

The answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210210/pkg-config-path-environment-variable/373217#373217) helped me figure out where pkg-config searches for installed libraries by default. The default path includes the `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig` directory where all `gstreamer-*-1.0.pc` are present. Therefore, it was just necessary to keep the default search paths of pkg-config so that the system could locate the gstreamer plugins.